# Ajax Action call throws an Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

It seems like I have a little mistake in my code. But I cant find it.

So, I'm calling an Action in my Controller from my ajax function.

```
var serviceURL = '/Vm/GetVMInformation';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: serviceURL,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("This Works fine");
        $("#testDiv").html(result); // Display the partial View in this div
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

My Action then returns a partial view and an list object.

```
public ActionResult GetVMInformation()
{
    List<VmInfo> VMListArray = new List<VmInfo>();
    ... Code ...
    return PartialView("_List", VmList);
}
```

The Action gets called and the partial View works. I tested it.
So the problem is, my ajax function isnt successful. So it throws an error. When I alert the error I just get "Internal Server Error".

Does anyone see my mistake?

Note:
My partial view. Not sure if its important

```
<!--This partial View is just for testing the ajax function-->

@model IsolutionsAzureManager.Models.VmData

<p>@Model.Name[0]</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

So I changed the return type of my function (which has now the type JsonResult) to Json

```
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string output = jss.Serialize(VmList);
    Response.Write(output);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    return Json("_List", output);
```

The good news: The ajax call is now successful.
The bad news: I still can't display my partial View. The return value (result) is just [object, Object]

```
    success: function (result) {
        $("#testDiv").html(result);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get a 500 error something is wrong in you application.

If you get a JS error it might be because your JS expects JSON in return, but since you return a partialview the return content is HTML. Your controller action should convert your list into a JSON  object, and the action return type should be a JsonResult.
Or you change the expected result type in your JS.

*Update

You see "object" because you are just throwing you JSON onject into the HTML. To display it correctly, you need to work with the object. Since it is a serialized list, you need to iterate over it do something with each entry.
Something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
    alert(result[i].name);
}
```

where ".name" would be some field from your `VmInfo` class.

Comment: So I updates my question. There is still a problem when displaying the partial view

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error means your server throw a exception and response 500 http status. You need debug `GetVMInformation` action see the reason.

Comment: `GetVMInformation()` seems to work fine. I dont get any expection